# update list item in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, workflow, update

I have two list(A and B) in the the same site collection. I need to update the item in list B based on list A.

Requirement:

If user select the drop down item of column name"Student category" in list A, it should be update the "Student category" of List B.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your preferences, you can create workflow using SharePoint Designer(easily created using UI) or you can use Event Receivers, but this approach requires full trust solution which may be too big in simple scenarios.

**UPDATE**

Sorry for a late response. Simple workflow to update item on a seperate list could look like this:
[image: Workflow]

You can create such a workflow via SharePoint Designer -> Lists and Libraries -> Your List -> List Workflow

Comment: Thanks rafter, Do you have any sample or link ? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can write JSOM code to update the item in list b in PreSaveAction() method.

Comment: Thanks Parag, Do you have sample link or if you did ?

Comment: to update item in sharepoint list 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/update-a-list-item-in-sharepoint-using-jsomannouncement-list

and call updatelistitem() in Presaveaction().