# How to update other fields when dropdown item is selected(Edited Question)

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, javascript

I have a look up field in List A, means item grabs from list B.  Whenever the user select an item from the dropdown, and set update 3 other fields in List B, depending on what was selected.  I need to be able to update the item for list B.

[update list item in SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/225801/update-list-item-in-sharepoint)

N.B:

I tried using Workflow(Update list item), but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: If you use Workflow(Update list item) between list items there must be an identifier that you use as an ID (Name, another value...)?

Comment: @ Mikhail, Thanks for prompt respond , I created a hidden field(Destination By Id),so Update list item dialog box under find the list item , I put Destination By Id(Field) and Value = Id

Comment: When Item created, Value assign Destination BY Id==Id

Comment: Ok, what is the log error your Workflow? I also recommend checking the values of your IDs, maybe they do not match.

Comment: When I changed the matching value to look up field, it through an error.

Comment: Oh,  it just created new Id. Why? means its doesn't match